# How do I override a computed value with EntityFramework 4.1 DbContext API

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4.1

I have a rowversion (`timestamp`) column which is set to computed in my EF designer.

Setting the value in code, via the direct property like

```
     myEnt.rowversion = screenRowVersion;
```

has now effect when `SaveChanges()` is called, a trace to SQLServer shows that the original value of rowversion is used.

Is it possible to have the DbContext API accept an **external** computed value?

Answer (score 1):

EF doesn't allow overriding computed values - it always uses original values loaded from the database. There is workaround for this where you cheat EF and change the original value tracked by the context:

```
context.Entry(myEnt).OriginalValues["rowversion"] = screenRowVersion;
```

But anyway in case of timestamp it is not needed. You have the old timestamp and a new timestamp so you can [compare them in your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672193/how-to-compare-sql-timestamp-in-net) without necessary roundtrip to database.